# The difference between running tests from AndroidStudio and gradle task

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, powermock

I have local tests which use mockito and powerMockito in my project. There are about 300 of them.
When I run them from the Android Studio (Run -> Run test configuration), all of them passed.
But our CI system launch it using gradle task testDebugUnitTest, which fails about 90 of them with different errors.

The question is: what is the difference between these mechanisms?

Comment: This is really broad as it depends on what the tests do, what they expect from the environment, how they fail, etc. It could be some files with relative paths, it could be environmental variables, differences between OS-es, it could be a difference in JDK, you name it... There is really not enough information provided to come to a sane conclusion. You'll have to investigate on your own and figure out what differences (maybe bugs in the tools) there are. If you can provide accurate information we can use to reproduce your scenario, then we can investigate. Otherwise we have no way of guessing.

Comment: Well, the question is actually: what happens when I click on the green button that says "Run" in android studio?  Gradle is run? Or what? I don't want to fix these 90 tests, it is another story.

Comment: If you run from Gradle, you're guaranteed it works. In my experience, running from Android Studio fails to re-build the tests and either uses cached ones from `./gradlew test` or says the test suite isn't found. This might be fixed in later versions though

Comment: Have you figured out what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Gradle(https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) plugin?

One must be aware that Android Studio build system is based on Gradle, and the Android plugin for Gradle adds several features that are specific to building Android apps. Although the Android plugin is typically updated in lock-step with Android Studio, the plugin (and the rest of the Gradle system) can run independent of Android Studio and be updated separately.

Official docs here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

So, if there are version and platform related differences, we should expect the results to be different.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Check which gradle task is run by Android studio when you do 'Run'. You can see this information in 'Event log' window [bottom right corner].

Comment: @RanjanKumar yeah, it's warmer. But I don't see who is running the tests. All I see is the jobs for preparing the binaries for testing.